# Change from API v2 to v3 TYPO3 Extension lumonet_googlemaps

Tags: google-maps

I used in the past an Google API Browser key (V2) for the TYPO3 Extension 'lumonet_googlemaps'. Now I have generate an V3 Key on the same way, but it dosen't work...

**Browser Key**
Access data that comes from a browser, and that is not associated with an account
Api Key AIzaSyDJ_USqTqBYiE-2btd3Gnlo.........
**Allowed referrers**
www.usedom-kaiserbaeder.de

The Extension is on http://www.usedom-kaiserbaeder.de/seebad-heringsdorf/ in the right bottom 'Übersicht Heringsdorf'.

I can't find the Reason of this Problem.